# How to get newly created user id in user_presave hook?

Tags: 8, users, hooks

Following is my .module file code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_presave().
 */

function cost_sheet_user_presave($account) {
    $source_userid = $account->id();
    \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t($source_userid));

}
```

This is giving me uid for already existing users when edited but not printing any value when a new user is created. How to get uid of newly created user in drupal 8 user presave hook?

Comment: Just check `$account->isNew()`

Comment: That is to check the account is new right ? How to get uid from newly created account ?

Comment: A new user/any entity can not have an ID before being saved the first time

Comment: Ho yeah @hudri fair enough. So in that case I think I should use hook entity insert right ? Because I want to set users ( both added and edited ) in some other entities.

Comment: First guess is: use `hook_entity_postsave()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the user ID in `hook_user_presave()` for a new user because the ID isn't assigned until the user is saved.

### So how do I run code that uses the user ID when saving a user, regardless of whether the user is new or has been edited?

Refactor your code that does something with the user ID into a function, `doStuffWithUserID()`.

```php
function mymodule_user_presave($account) {
  if (!$account->isNew()) {
    doStuffWithUserID();
  }
}

function mymodule_user_insert($account) {
  // The new account has been saved, so we have an ID.
  doStuffWithUserID();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I almost forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

The only hooks called after an entity is saved in the database are [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/9.3.x) for updated entities, and [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/9.3.x) for new entities. Once the entity is stored in the database, its ID will have a value.

Unfortunately, Drupal core doesn't use any `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_postsave()` which would make sense as it uses `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()`.

This means that your module should implement `cost_sheet_user_update()` and `cost_sheet_user_insert()`.

Keep in mind that [`EntityStorageBase::doPostSave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AdoPostSave/9.3.x) invokes either one or the other of those hooks. Their code doesn't need to check whether the entity is new.

```php
// Allow code to run after saving.
$entity->postSave($this, $update);
$this->invokeHook($update ? 'update' : 'insert', $entity);
```